# How does package hosting work Opencpu

Tags: opencpu

I wonder if I must host my R package on opencpu cloud server or GistHub even if I use my own Opencpu server on Amazon?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use the OpenCPU apps offline, if you install the server on your own computer. No matter what R packages are needed. You only need to install them on your server!

Comment: Ok! And if I gonna host my server on Amazon, then I can host my opencpu server there?:)